# Need Syntax Help, asp:SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct for my SqlDataSource. I'm using a mySQL database and the connection string is in the web.config file. I have this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsEditEvents" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString = <%$ ConnectionStrings["mySQLConnectionString"] %>
    SelectCommand="SELECT EventID, EventName, EventDate FROM Events ORDER BY EventID" 
    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
    onselected="sdsShelfLifeMaster_Selected">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My error is "The server tag is not well formed."

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to quote them.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsEditEvents" runat="server"
    ConnectionString ='<%$ ConnectionStrings["mySQLConnectionString"] %>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT EventID, EventName, EventDate FROM Events ORDER BY EventID" 
    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
    onselected="sdsShelfLifeMaster_Selected">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Good catch. I'm still not working, the error is the same.

Comment: Oops. We had quot inside quot. I've changed the outer to single quot to escape the ones inside

Comment: I changed the syntax to an easier format; ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:mySQLConnectionString %>" and it's working now, thanks!